# matrix programming sum function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, logic

I have a square matrix "a" below as an example see below. matrix a, is nxn square matrix.

```
a = matrix( 
  c(1, 5 , 3, 7 , 3,
    5, 1, 2, 2, 4,
    3, 2 , 1, 2,4,
    7, 2, 2,1,3,
    2, 4,4 ,3 , 1   
   ),ncol = 5,nrow =5)
```

I'm trying to write a function(x) in R as below in order to provide this to an optimization routine. I'm trying to minimize function(x), where x is unknown. x is vector.

```
sumx <- function(x) {

sum(((a[i,j]*a[j,k])-(x[i]/x[j]))^2) for all i,j,k such that i not eq to j not eq to k
}
```

Can you please help in programming this logic and function in R?

Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry but what is `x` (seems to be a vector) and what is `a` (the matrix b?). What do you want to achieve?

Comment: sgibb, sorry i was not clear, i have edited my question. yes, x is vector and i'm trying to minimize the function(x) using one of the optimization routine in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
comb3 <- function(n){
    result <- expand.grid(i=1:n,j=1:n,k=1:n)
    result[with(result, i!=j & j!=k & i!=k & j>i),]
}
```

EDIT: I've phrased the conditions as `i!=j & j!=k & i!=k & j>i` to be more readable and include the condition you mentioned in comments.

```
sumx <- function(x) {
    sum(with(comb3(length(x)), ((a[cbind(i,j)]*a[cbind(j,k)])-(x[i]/x[j]))^2))
}
```

Example:

```
sumx(1:5)
#[1] 3584.542
```

Note that I've replaced `a[i,j]` with `a[cbind(i,j)]` to allow vectorized access to elements of the matrix.

You can now put `sumx` to optimize, but it may be better to save `comb3(length(x))` and the part that does not depend on `x` as a global object to reduce computation time, like this:

```
y <- within(comb3(nrow(a)), b <- a[cbind(i,j)]*a[cbind(j,k)])

sumx <- function(x) {
    sum(with(y, (b-(x[i]/x[j]))^2))
}
```

For minimization, you can use `optim`. Note that I've found two different attractors:

```
> optim(rep(1,5), sumx)
$par
[1] 1.9739966 1.5882750 1.5626338 0.1592725 0.1521839

$value
[1] 1436.526

$counts
function gradient 
     502       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL

> optim(1:5, sumx)
$par
[1] 5.4254668 4.3857303 4.3029354 0.4374246 0.4199909

$value
[1] 1436.503

$counts
function gradient 
     218       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Ferdinand.kraft, Absolutely brilliant. I missed one other contion which is "j is always greater than i / j>i" I would really apreciate if you could please modify the code - comb3 ?

Comment: once again, @Ferdinand.kraft brilliantly done. Many thanks for your assistance in this highly efficient code.